# What does Cassandra nodetool repair exactly do?

Tags: cassandra

From http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_repair_nodes_c.html I know that

> The nodetool repair command repairs inconsistencies across all of the replicas for a given range of data.

- but how does it fix the inconsistencies? It's written it uses Merkle trees - but that's for comparison not for fixing 'broken' data.
- How the data can be 'broken'? Any common cases despite hard drive failure?

Question aside: it's compaction which evicts tombstones, right? So the requirement for running nodetool repair more frequently than gc_grace seconds is only to ensure that all data is spread to appropriate replicas? Shouldn't be that the usual scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data can become inconsistent whenever a write to a replica is not completed for whatever reason.  This can happen if a node is down, if the node is up but the network connection is down, if a queue fills up and the write is dropped, disk failure, etc.

When inconsistent data is detected by comparing the merkle trees, the bad sections of data are repaired by streaming them from the nodes with the newer data.  Streaming is a basic mechanism in Cassandra and is also used for bootstrapping empty nodes into the cluster.

The reason you need to run repair within gc grace seconds is so that tombstones will be sync'd to all nodes.  If a node is missing a tombstone, then it won't drop that data during compaction.  The nodes with the tombstone will drop the data during compaction, and then when they later run repair, the deleted data can be resurrected from the node that was missing the tombstone.

Comment: Thank you. Just to be clear, "The data can become inconsistent whenever a write to a replica is not completed for whatever reason." - Cassandra uses hinted handoff to mitigate this, right? Hinted handoff is fired automatically, therefore that state is possible, but rare?

Comment: Cassandra has a couple of mechanisms to help keep the data consistent.  Hinted handoff will store writes that would fail due to a node being down and will complete them when the node comes back up.  But it only works for a limited amount of downtime, so if the node is down longer than the hint window, you will start to miss writes.  The other mechanism is read repair chance, which will slowly repair data when reads are done.  If you have good hardware and a good network, then inconsistent data is somewhat rare, but it can still happen.

Comment: hinted handoffs are held for the default value of 3 hours. if a node is down for longer than that period the hints are dropped. Also, if there are a large number of hints, the 'hint buffer' may overflow and some hints will be dropped. in either case, the data is left in an inconsistent state.