# Purpose of regular nodetool repair on cassandra nodes

Tags: cassandra

I'm working my way through the documentation and self paced video courses so please bear with me.

It's recommended that `nodetool repair` is run frequently on each node, what isn't clear is why.

When you make a write, the coordinator sends the request to the primary token holder node, and also to the other replicas. Assuming all nodes are up, all nodes should be in sync in a short period of time. I'm assuming that both deletes and updates work in the same way as an insert, with the addition of the tombstone markers for deletes.

So in a perfect case where no nodes ever go down and you have little network latency, what is the advantage of running `nodetool repair`?

In a realistic case where nodes do go down, running `nodetool repair` allows the downed nodes to resync where the handoff hints have expired.

In what scenario could data be resurrected? Is it only where a node has been down longer than the gc_grace_period? or is this really an issue where network latency could be large?

Also, how do you effectively schedule the job on each node so that they don't overlap? It would have to be dynamically scheduled as the size of the cluster changed, also you'd presumably not know how long it was going to take.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming no failures, running repairs is optional.

- The Cassandra wiki notes that that if failures do not occur, you can just get by with HintedHandoff. https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Operations#Repairing_missing_or_inconsistent_data
- Datastax also expand on this; if you only delete by TTL and have synchronised time and therefore, I guess, don't have to worry about tombstones and gc_grace_seconds + max_hint_window. http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/advanced-repair-techniques

Having said that, the design of Cassandra assumes that some kind of failure will occur; when running on commodity hardware, something will always break.

In terms of scheduling repair to avoid "overlap", I’m assuming you mean trying to minimise performance degradation when querying a range that is being repaired:

- Use sequential repair (each replica repaired in turn) rather than parallel (where the Merkle trees for all nodes are constructed at the same time). However there are trade-offs in that sequential will generate snapshots each time and won't complete the overall process as quickly.
- Use incremental repair (although this will have an impact on your compaction strategy)
- You can also control whether repair should be run in a particular DC or cluster-wide

Comment: Check out also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32340429/what-does-cassandra-nodetool-repair-exactly-do

Comment: Thank you both, it makes more sense now.